# How to fix overlapping graph?

Tags: graphs

I am adding figures to my paper but the text is overlapping the graph. I want the graph to cover the two columns as it is wide.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1 \textwidth]{X2.png}
    \caption{model main processes.}
    \label{graph_X2}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You need to create a MWE (minimal working example) that is compilable and illustrates your problem. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: If you want to include a `figure` that spans across both columns, you need to use `figure*` instead.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks, it works, please put as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using a document class which prints in `twocolumn` mode (e.g., when you're using `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`), you can use `figure` to input a float that spans only a single column. If you want to include a float that spans both columns you have to use the `figure*` environment instead. Note that `figure*` has restricted placement options.